# Varirable scopes in python

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

why is the scope different for `int` and `list` in Python? Below is my example

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Foo:
    def method(self):
        l = []
        i = 0
        def method1():
            l.append(1)
            i =  i + 1 <<<<<< Throws exception
        method1()
    Foo().method()
```

In the above example, I can access the list `l` inside my `method1` function but not the integer `i`. Any possible explanation?

I referred to the below link, but it had no explanation about the above scenario.

[Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Because you're assigning to `i` (but not to `l`) inside `method1`. If you assign to a variable in a function, the variable is local to the function unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Yup, any variable that is assigned inside a function is  local by default.

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood already answered in comment section it's assignment thing.
You refer to list, but assign an int.
If you refer to int it will also work as list:

```
class Foo:
    def method(self):
        l = []
        i = 0
        def method1():
            l.append(1)
            m = i + 1
            print(m)
        method1()
Foo().method()
```